# Entity Framework forming virtual collections to tables that use composite primary keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In entity framework, how do you link a virtual collection to another table that uses composite keys? Here's two example tables:

```cs
public abstract class Table1
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2 { get; private set; }
}
```

and

```cs
public abstract class Table2
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public string DetailKey { get; set; }
    public string DetailValue { get; set; }

    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
}
```

Meaning that in Table1, an event is added, and then using a one-to-many relationship, N number of rows are added to Table2. In Table1, the Guid `EventId` is the PK, in Table 2, the PK is composite of `EventId + DetailKey`, meaning that there could be N rows in Table2 related to the corresponding `EventId` in Table1. Table2 also has an FK of `EventId` to Table1's EventId.

The map file for Table1 looks like this (in part):

```cs
public override void ConfigureImp(EntityTypeBuilder<Table1> builder)
{
    base.ConfigureImp(builder);

    // Relationships            
    builder.HasMany(t => t.Table2)
          .WithOne(t => t.Table1)
          .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.EventId, x.DetailKey });
}
```

the map file for Table2 looks like this (in part):

```cs
public override void ConfigureImp(EntityTypeBuilder<Table2> builder)
{
    base.ConfigureImp(builder);

    // Relationships
    builder.HasOne(t => t.Table1)
         .WithMany(t => t.Table2)
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
         .IsRequired();
}
```

Let's add some data, say 1 row to Table1 with EventId `FOO`, and 5 rows to Table2, where each row in Table2 has the same EventId (to satisfy the FK) but a unique DetailKey (to satisfy the composite key). After doing this, I run a query like this:

```
Table1 target = db.Table1
                    .Include(x => x.Table2)
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.EventId.Equals("FOO"));
```

Upon doing this, and inspecting the contents of `target` (say, as a breakpoint) I would expect to see the details from Table1, as well as all 5 rows from Table2 because of the `.Include`. However, what I am actually getting is only a single row from Table2, whichever row comes first in the table (meaning it can change as other rows for that `EventId` are added to Table2.

Any thoughts as to why I'm not getting all corresponding rows from Table2 using queries such as the one shown above for `target`? Thank you.

Comment: where is the method you are using to insert into the db? "...getting is only a single row from Table2" you mean from the db right?

Comment: Yes, from the DB. For the sake of the example, the data could get to the DB manually. So in the `target` example at the end `db` is the database context that contains the `Table1` and `Table2` models.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to declare the relationship twice, and the Foreign Key is just EventId.

eg

```
public  class Event
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EventDetail> Details { get; private set; }
}
public class EventDetail
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public string DetailKey { get; set; }
    public string DetailValue { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event{ get; set; }
}
```

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{


     modelBuilder.Entity<EventDetail>()
         .HasOne(t => t.Event)
         .WithMany(t => t.Details)
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
         .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<EventDetail>().HasKey(e => new { e.EventId, e.DetailKey });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Would declaring it twice cause this type of behavior, where only one of the joined rows comes back? My logic for both sides was so I could make this style request in addition to my example above:
```
Table2 target = db.Table2
                    .Include(x => x.Table1)
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Table1.EventId.Equals("FOO"));
```
(Like to go the opposite direction)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just want to add that I tried this with the changed key style, and it has the same behavior as before (I get a single row from the `Include`, not none, and not all), so I think there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add the necessary attributes and you'd should be able to avoid the methods you wrote:

```
public  class Event
{
    [Key]
    public virtual Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual string EventName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EventDetail> Details { get; set; }
}
public class EventDetail
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public virtual Guid EventId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual string DetailKey { get; set; }
    public virtual string DetailValue { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event{ get; set; }
}
```